# Trying to reverse strings but there are spaces after reversing the string

Tags: go

I was trying to write a stringReverse function which reverses the given string:

```
func reverseString(s string) []rune
```

well, i did succeed but the problem is there are spaces after reversing it.

Input: "Hello, 世界"

Output: [界 世   , o l l e H]

code of function :

```
func reverseString(s string) []rune {
// sir: string in rune
sir := []rune(s)

for i, _ := range sir {
    sir[i], sir[len(sir)-i-1] = sir[len(sir)-i-1], sir[i]
    if i >= len(sir)-i-1 {
        return sir
    }
}
return sir
}
```

i did not do any error implementation since i am new to go.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you see this output in console?

Comment: The spaces you see is because you return a slice of runes, and slices are printed using spaces between the elements. Convert the result to `string`, and print that. There are no extra spaces in that. But there's also an error in your code: you only have to iterate to half of the string. If you go till the end, you might end up switching certain letters twice, moving them back to their original position. So loop only until `i >= (len(sir)-1)/2`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but be aware that reversing a general Unicode string is not trivial (because of combining characters, etc).

Comment: To complement @icza's comment, using two loop variables (one incrementing, the other decrementing, until the two values cross) is easier and less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

To reverse strings,you can declare an empty string and then start appending the characters from the end, one by one.Here is a sample code for the same logic:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func reverse(str string) (result string) {
    for _, v := range str {
        result = string(v) + result

    }
    return
}

func main() {

    runeStr := "Hello, 世界"
    fmt.Println(runeStr)
    runeRev := reverse(runeStr)
    fmt.Println(runeRev)

}
```

Output:

```
Hello, 世界
界世 ,olleH
```

Answer (score 0):

try to

```
func reverseString(s string) []rune {
    // sir: string in rune
    sir := []rune(s)
    
    for i, _ := range sir {
    
        sir[i], sir[len(sir)-i-1] = sir[len(sir)-i-1], sir[i]
        if i+1 >= len(sir)/2 {
            return sir
        }
    }
    return sir
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.